# Column creation based on NaN condition

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I am new to PANDAS and I have a question. I have a PANDAS data frame which is like this:

```
        A      B
  1     4      NaN
  2     5      NaN
  3     NaN     3
  4     5       10
  5     NaN    NaN
```

and I want to create a new variable that takes the values of A, but replaces them with the values of B if A is NaN:

```
                A      B      C
          1     4      NaN    4
          2     5      NaN    5
          3     NaN     3     3
          4     5       10    5
          5     NaN    NaN    NaN
```

How can I do it in PANDAS?

Comment: For your specific case, it is `df['C'] = df['A'].combine_first(df['B'])`

Comment: Aychan, thanks so much for the fast response, it works!